# Remove/Delete/Undo Parts

Tags: revit-api, revit, revit-2015

I have splitted the wall into parts. Now I want to remove the parts and keep the original wall. How do I remove/delete/undo the parts that have already been created? I have the partids which I would like to remove.

.ActiveDoc.Delete(partid) doesn't work out and throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by deleting the PartMaker associated with the source element:

```
revitDoc.Delete(PartUtils.GetAssociatedPartMaker(revitDoc, SourceElementId).Id);
```

Have fun!